# Appending DB object string to dynamic urls in Django

Tags: django, templates, templatetags

I need to append a string stored in DB. e.g ?linkappend which is stored as a DB object `link_append` to all ebay links that will be displayed in a page. I think I should use template tags but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You say that `link_append` is an object in the database? How is it stored? How does your view look like?

Because, if `link_append` is just represented by a ModelField, then it should be fairly easy to append it to the links by adding it as a template-variable like so:

```
<a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url}}?{{ obj.link_append }}"></a>
```

The part after "?" `{{ obj.link_append }}` does place the content of that ModelField in the GET-part of the link.